# Is there any way to quickly switch private endpoint on/off?

Tags: azure-virtual-network, azure-webapps, azure-private-link

I have an Azure web app that its inbound traffic is limited to a private endpoint and it has only a private ip. The setup is working well and I have a VM inside the subnet that I can browse my Azure web app.

The is a dev environment and I need to experiment/verify something.

Is there anyway to toggle off the private endpoint, have the web app available to public internet for a period of time, the toggle on the private endpoint?

I know I can remove webapp from its vent, but I am hoping to find a quick way to toggle the private endpoint off and off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduce the issue and find that toggle on and off can't be done.

1 simple thing you can do is to remove the private endpoint by going to the webapps >> networking>>private endpoints >> select the endpoint and remove from your webapp and again when require you can create it.

Added a private endpoint it got turn on but there is no option to turn it off.

[image]

Only one option it would be remove the private end to make it turn off.

[image]